# Run vue component only if element loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a small vue.js component defined on a javascript.

Is any elegant way to instance the vue component only when the element is loaded?

The issue is I am receiving these warnings in other htmls where the element is not present:

```
vue.js:485 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #item
```

Because it's running this js everywhere

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#item',
  });
```

How is it taken care of in vue.js?

Comment: Your problem could be solve with this previous post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484431/vue-warn-cannot-find-element

Comment: onload wont work on html pages which dont have the #item element

Comment: Do you load your element with an ajax request ? I don't understand why it is not present on the first load

Comment: Because you can have a index.html with a <div id="item"></div> which wont give problems to Vue and then a stuff.html which wont have any <div id="item"></div> and when javascript vue.js get executed in that page will complain because the #item element is not present in the page

Comment: Can't you just load your script on the files with the #item element ?

Comment: yeah... that's exactly what I am asking... and with elegant I mean a vue way to take care of that, not just a document.getElementById("#item"), imagine I have 100 vue components...

Comment: Well I was talking about including your vue <script> tag only in the files that have your #item element, so you don't need to write any condition in js but I guess you are in the situation with a single big js file with/or a module bundler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for the element before creating the instance.

```
if(document.getElementById("#item")){
  new Vue({
    el: '#item',
  });
}
```

Comment: yeah I was thinking on this but it didnt look so elegant to me, is this then the only way to do this?

Comment: I don't know of a vue-only way. However, this is only a warning, which means you shouldn't see it in production with debug mode off, if that's any conciliation.

Comment: ok, will leave this question open for a while and if nobody know a vue-only way I accept this answer